# How to know which slash (forward or backslash) will be used as folder separator on a Cloud Run Node.js dockerized environment?

Tags: node.js, docker, path, google-cloud-run

I'm running my `express` server on a Node.js environment on Cloud Run (docker container).

I need to access the `__filename` variable in one of my functions.

How can I know which slash will be returned as folder separator? forward or backslash?

Is this defined only by Node itself or should I look which OS that Node environment will be created on?

On my local Powershell Windows, it comes back as a backslash `\`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you upload your image to Googles Docker registry can you try to run your image locally and see how it works. It should work in the same way in your Cloud Run container.

Cloud Run supports only Linux containers, so it should be with forwardslash: **/**

You can try to run it local with the following commands:

1. Navigate to the folder with your Dockerfile in
2. Build the container with `docker build -t myimage .`
3. Wait for build to complete...
4. Run now the container with: `docker run myimage`

I think maybe you would like to expose ports from the container on your machine. You can do that with this command: `docker run -p 3000:3000 myimage` (it will expose your container to http://localhost:3000

Comment: I'm using this image: `FROM node:12-slim` on my `Dockerfile`. [link](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/) Does that imply a Linux OS? EDIT: Sorry, now I've realized you've said that it **only** supports Linux containers. So it should be. I usually avoid to run docker locally. I always find it to be a pain to run locally. When I do it, I'm always having trouble with containers that keep running, images that were not deleted, etc. I usually test it locally with `nodemon` and ship it to a test environment on the cloud where I can test the Docker behavior before production.